# Calls to DDASPK solver in Fortran77 giving strange results for certain points in array

Tags: arrays, fortran, numerical-methods, solver, fortran77

I'm using DDASPK to solve a parabolic PDE by the method of lines. Here is the subroutine that the solver is calling:

```
SUBROUTINE RES(T,Y,YPRIME,CJ,DELTA,IRES,IPAR,RPAR)

  IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H, O-Z)
  DIMENSION Y(*), YPRIME(*), DELTA(*), V(201), LAP3V(201)
  H = 0.05D0
  NPTS = 201

  DO 50 I = 1,NPTS
     V(I) = Y(I+1)
50   CONTINUE

  DO 60 J = 4,(NPTS-3)
     LAP3V(J) = (V(J-3) - 6.0D0*V(J-2) + 15.0D0*V(J-1) - 
 &   20.0D0*V(J) + 15.0D0*V(J+1) - 6.0D0*V(J+2) + 
 &   V(J+3))/(H**6.0D0)
60   CONTINUE

  LAP3V(1) = (2.0D0*V(4) - 12.0D0*V(3) + 30.0D0*V(2) - 
 &20.0D0*V(1))/(H**6.0D0)
  LAP3V(2) = (V(5) - 6.0D0*V(4) + 16.0D0*V(3) - 26.0D0*V(2) +
 &15.0D0*V(1))/(H**6.0D0)
  LAP3V(3) = (V(6) - 6.0D0*V(5) + 15.0D0*V(4) - 20.0D0*V(3) + 
 &16.0D0*V(2) - 6.0D0*V(1))/(H**6.0D0)
  LAP3V(NPTS-2) = 0.0D0
  LAP3V(NPTS-1) = 0.0D0
  LAP3V(NPTS) = 0.0D0

  DELTA(1) = YPRIME(1) - 1.0D0
  DO 70 K = 1,NPTS
     DELTA(K+1) = YPRIME(K+1) - LAP3V(K)
 70   CONTINUE

  RETURN
  END
```

Here LAP3V is a discretized third power of the laplacian in 1D (so sixth derivative), and in the first column we have coupled it with the simple ODE dy(1)/dt = 1 (Why, you ask? When I can get this up and running I'm ultimately going to be solving more difficult PDEs for which it's better to couple the time step the solver takes with some aspect of the solution).

However, when I try and call it from the solver (which is fully implicit, so its first job will be to calculate a consistent YPRIME given an input Y at T = 0), everything seems to work except at two points - in the first entry of the array, it quickly goes from zero (I put YPRIME(1) = 1 at time zero as an initial guess) to inf, and then -nan , for reasons I don't understand - that should be the easy part. Also at YPRIME(NPTS-3), we quickly end up with a very large negative number (around -1e9) while the entries surrounding it are, quite rightly, zero. I believe this must have something to do with this being the final entry assigned in the do loop as opposed to case by case, but I'm not really familiar enough with fortran to understand what or how to fix it.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's the former (and in fact I got the numbers the wrong way round - it's actually more like -1.4e9). Still, rather farther away from zero than I can fathom.

Comment: No, definitely -1.4e9. It's a long way away from zero in the negative direction.

Comment: It would be good to come up with an example we can try to run, e.g., some definition of the subroutine arguments which leads to the problem.

Comment: my initial Y is [0,exp(-x^2)] where x goes from 0 to 10, at some number of points. My initial YPRIME is [1,0,...,0]. Any implicit solver than calculates consistent initial conditions should be able to handle it. I could reproduce the entirety of my code here, but I doubt anyone really wants to download and compile it with DASPK  to get it to work? 

I was hoping I'd missed something obvious.

Comment: Who knows, I will definitely not try to understand code which begins with something different than `implicit none `. Especially when I cannot try it.

Comment: this is a user supplied subroutine, not part of the package.  the hard coded dimension `201` throws a warning for me-are you certain thats consistent with your usage?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned it's not part of the program. Originally I tried to pass parameters such as the number of mesh points/mesh size from the main program into the subroutine with the ipar/rpar arrays provided specifically for that purpose. However, As soon as I initialized them within the subroutine something would go haywire and the values I stored would be replaced by garbage. I have no idea why - I'm fairly sure my iwork and rwork arrays have the correct size. Initializing the parameters from scratch inside the subroutine has worked better for me except for at the two points.

Answer (score 1):

Without the full source, it is difficult to know exactly what is occurring.

However, in my experience, whenever array values start taking strange values (Inf, NaN, etc.), it is almost always due to incorrectly referencing an array value. Improper array references will result in using memory referring to other variables or even to where parts of the binary executable are stored (in this case an assignment to that location will usually result in a seg fault and a program crash).

There are several possible common scenarios to check (this is not necessarily exhaustive!):

1. With implicit variables, it's very easy to accidentally use a previously undeclared and uninitialized variable.
2. With assumed size arrays (e.g., Y(*)), it's very easy to accidentally read or write past the end of the array (e.g., in your DO 50 loop if Y doesn't have at least 202 elements, you have a problem!). Make sure that all of your arrays are appropriately dimensioned.
3. If you have declared an allocatable array but failed to allocate it, it can seem to work but fail in very strange ways.
4. Your comment about having your IPAR and RPAR arrays being trashed suggests to me that there may also a bug in one of the other routines that's resulting in an out-of-bounds array assignment.

Also remember that trying to solve a set of nonlinear equations to obtain a consistent derivative is highly nontrivial and can result in no valid solutions being found. There isn't much you can do about it except try to find a better initial guess and/or try to calculate the derivative analytically (if you can do it).

Finally, one final tip for using DASPK. The solver doesn't care what version Fortran the RES subroutine is in. Rewrite the RES subroutine in Fortran 90, and you will be much happier in the long run! (This applies to the rest of the code too. Fortran 90 is /so much better/ than Fortran 77, that it's insane to write new Fortran 77 unless you have no other alternative.)

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! You're quite right about it being better to use fortran 90 but some of the dependencies you need to link to ddaspk will only compile with f77. gfortran doesn't work. I'll have a careful look at my array indexing. Curiously, when I compile and run the example programs that come with daspk the ipar and roar arrays work fine. Suggesting that the rest of the program is bug free? Thanks again, though.